flask-login: после авторизации перебрасывает на none страницу
Написал методы регистрации и авторизации. Регистрация работает исправно, данные в базу записываются. Но когда хочу авторизоваться, при вводе корректного логина и пароля, которые записаны в базе данных, перебрасывает не на redirect(next_page), а на url #/none. Как исправить?
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    if login and password:
        user = User.query.filter_by(login=login).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)

            next_page = request.args.get('next')

            return redirect(next_page)
        else:
            flash('Неправильный логин или пароль')
    else:
        flash('Пожалуйста заполните поля авторизации')

    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/logout', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    login = request.form.get('login')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    password2 = request.form.get('password2')

    if request.method == "POST":
        if not (login or password or password2):
            flash('Пожалуйста заполните поля')
        elif password != password2:
            flash('Пароли не совпадают')
        else:
            hash_pwd = generate_password_hash(password)
            new_user = User(login=login, password=hash_pwd)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('register.html')


@app.after_request
def redirect_to_signin(response):
    if response.status_code == 401:
        return redirect(url_for('login') + '?next=' + request.url)

    return response
{% block content %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container_auth">
        <h2 class="authnamecon">Авторизация</h2>
        <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}" class="auth-register-btn">Регистрация</a>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                <div class=flashes>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <p>{{ message }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        <form id="signin" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input class="auth-form" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required>
            <input class="pass-form" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required>
            <button class="btn-auth-form" type="submit">Войти</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="section-separator-figure"></div>
{% endblock content %}


Ну для начала логичный вопрос — а этот самый next_page в адресной строке браузера вообще имеется?
